# Calculate variance between two array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two data sets from the same API call on two different dates and I want to calculate variance between values of those two arrays of objects received using javascript. The following are two data sets.

```
const arrayOne = [
        {
            id: 1,
            values: {
                sales: {
                    rawValue: 3,
                    value: '3.0',
                },
            },
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            values: {
                sales: {
                    rawValue: 1,
                    value: '1.0',
                },
            },
        },
    ];

const arrayTwo = [
        {
            id: 1,
            values: {
                sales: {
                    rawValue: 1.1,
                    value: '1.1',
                },
            },
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            values: {
                sales: {
                    rawValue: 2,
                    value: '2.0',
                },
            },
        },
    ];
```

I am trying to create a new array with the following objects with calculated variance init:

```
const newArray = [
        {
            id: 1,
            values: {
                salesVar: {
                    rawValue: calculatedVariance,
                    value: 'calculatedVariance',
                },
            },
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            values: {
                salesVar: {
                    rawValue: calculatedVariance,
                    value: 'calculatedVariance',
                },
            },
        },
    ];
```

Is there any possible solution for this using javascript?

Comment: How do you calculate the variance between two numbers? `(num1 - num2) / num2` or something different?

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah sort of `const variance = ((firstValue - secondValue) / firstValue) * 100` like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the two arrays contain objects of the same shape and in the same order, then it is very simple to use [Lodash's `mergeWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/#mergeWith) to combine the two. The function accepts a customiser argument which can do the calculation:

```js
const numberFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", { 
  type: "decimal",
  minimumFractionDigits: 1,
  maximumFractionDigits: 20,
});

const calculateVariance = (firstValue, secondValue) =>
  ((firstValue - secondValue) / firstValue) * 100

const calculateVarianceAsString = (firstValue, secondValue) =>
  numberFormatter.format(
    calculateVariance(Number(firstValue), Number(secondValue))
  );
  
function combineWithVariance(arr1, arr2) {
  return _.mergeWith(arr1, arr2, (a, b, key) => {
    if (key === "rawValue")
      return calculateVariance(a, b);
    if (key === "value")
      return calculateVarianceAsString(a, b);
  });
}

const arrayOne = [{ id: 1, values: { sales: { rawValue: 3  , value: '3.0', },},}, { id: 2, values: { sales: { rawValue: 1, value: '1.0', },},},]; 
const arrayTwo = [{ id: 1, values: { sales: { rawValue: 1.1, value: '1.1', },},}, { id: 2, values: { sales: { rawValue: 2, value: '2.0', },},},];

console.log(combineWithVariance(arrayOne, arrayTwo));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

In this case, the customiser only handles `rawValue` and `value` properties. For everything else, the customiser just returns `undefined` which allows Lodash to handle the recursive merging by automatically.

For the cases where the result is handled by the customiser, `calculateVariance()` handles the calculation, while `calculateVarianceAsString()` formats the result using [`Intl.NumberFormat#format()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/format) to show a ".0" at the end of the number, even if it does not have fractional part. But Show as much of the fraction as possible otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating variance is straightforward - the difficult part is navigating around the data structures.

```js
const arrayOne = [{"id":1,"values":{"sales":{"rawValue":3,"value":"3.0"}}},{"id":2,"values":{"sales":{"rawValue":1,"value":"1.0"}}}]
const arrayTwo = [{"id":1,"values":{"sales":{"rawValue":1.1,"value":"1.1"}}},{"id":2,"values":{"sales":{"rawValue":2,"value":"2.0"}}}]

const input = [arrayOne, arrayTwo]

const sums = input.flat()
  .reduce((a,{id, values:{sales:{rawValue}}}) =>
    (a[id]??=0, a[id]+=rawValue, a), {})

const counts = input.flat()
  .reduce((a,{id}) => (a[id]??=0, a[id]+=1, a), {})

const means = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(sums).map(([id, sum]) => ([id, sum/counts[id]])))

const sumsValueMinusMeanSquared = input.flat()
  .reduce((a,{id, values:{sales:{rawValue}}}) =>
    (a[id]??=0, a[id]+=Math.pow(rawValue-means[id], 2), a), {})

const sumsValueMinusMeanSquaredDivN = 
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(
    sumsValueMinusMeanSquared).map(([id, x])=>[id, x/counts[id]]))

console.log(sums)
console.log(counts)
console.log(means)
console.log(sumsValueMinusMeanSquared)
console.log(sumsValueMinusMeanSquaredDivN)

const output = Object.entries(sumsValueMinusMeanSquaredDivN)
  .map(([id, variance]) =>
    ({id, values: {salesVar: {rawValue: variance, value: String(variance)}}}))

console.log(output)
```